# Ordering in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I have a situation where I am importing many rows of data from text files. The import process occurs using SqlBulkCopy and initially loads into a staging table.

I perform some validation on this data and would like to be able to report back to the user which line of the file is in error if validation fails. I was hoping to simply use ROW_NUMBER() along with the default ordering of the SELECT on my staging table, but there are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5628674/685760) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110735/685760) on SO that have suggested I won't be able to do this.

What would you suggest as a method to allow me to retain the original order of the input file? The input file format is TSV. Do I need to create a mock value indicating file-line?

Is there any way to report the result of the query in the order of the original insertions? Could I rely on this given I used SqlBulkCopy to load the date en masse?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I am able to preserve source table order using `BULK INSERT` into a file, followed by adding an identity.

Given a tab-delimited table, `C:\MyTable.txt`, where I intentionally moved rows out of order:

```
FileName    FileType
wmsetup log
bar txt
wmsetup10   log
WMSysPr9    prx
WMSysPrx    prx
Wudf01000Inst   log
xpsp1hfm    log
_default    pif
0   log
002391_ tmp
005766_ tmp
```

I ran the following and preserved the text file order in SQL Server:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id=t.schema_id
    WHERE t.name='myTable'
    AND t.[type]='U'
    AND s.name='dbo'
)
DROP TABLE myTable
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable(FileName VARCHAR(80), FileType VARCHAR(30))
GO

BULK INSERT myTable FROM 'C:\MyTable.txt' WITH (
firstrow=2
, fieldterminator='\t'
, rowterminator='\n'
)
GO

ALTER TABLE myTable ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
GO

SELECT * FROM myTable
GO
```

Result:

```
FileName        FileType ID
--------------- -------- -----------
wmsetup         log      1
bar             txt      2
wmsetup10       log      3
WMSysPr9        prx      4
WMSysPrx        prx      5
Wudf01000Inst   log      6
xpsp1hfm        log      7
_default        pif      8
0               log      9
002391_         tmp      10
005766_         tmp      11
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Everything I've read thus far suggests this isn't true though. [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189694/how-to-keep-row-order-with-sqlbulkcopy) suggests it won't work with SqlBulkCopy, and there are [other posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/Bc9HhokagYA) that suggest there little that can be done to ensure order of insert. The only promising thing I came across was point 4 of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx, but that doesn't help me with bulk inserts. Thanks.

Comment: If the bulk insert + identity doesn't work for you as it did for me here, your only remaining option might be a shell script to insert an RowID counter directly into the flat files before bulk inserting. Perl makes this sort of thing easy.

Comment: Thanks John. I've ended up doing much the same as you suggest. Editing the input as it's read to append a RowNumber column. I was just hoping there was some way I could get around it. Having said that, it is worth while investigating your own solution a little further though to ensure it is behaving as you expect. As mentioned earlier, it seems as though there is definitive way to preserve order during bulk insert or through SqlBulkCopy unless the order is defined in the source file. Also you can't guarantee order on your select unless you have an associated order by clause. Thanks again.