# SqlBulkCopy insert order

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

To copy data from one database to another in different server with same schema, I am planning to use SqlBulkCopy class from C sharp library. Whether SqlBulkCopy will maintain the same order as it is in the datatable while inserting the records ?

Example: id is the identity column.

Server1, db1

```
TableA
id   name
1    name10
2    name20
3    name30
4    name40
```

Server2, db1

```
TableA
    id   name
    1    name1
    2    name2
    3    name3
    4    name4
    ..........
    ..........
    5000 name22
    5001 name33
```

- Step1: `var dt = select * from server1.dbo.TableA order by id;`
- Step2: SQL bulk copy into server2 `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);`
- Step3: `var resultDt = select top 4 id from server2.dbo.TableA order by id desc.` Since we know the number of records we inserted I am using "top 4".
- Step4: `resultDt.DefaultView.Sort = "id asc";`

**Question:** Whether id in resultDt will represent id in dt for all the rows ? i.e,.

```
5002 from server2 = 1 from server1
5003 from server2 = 2 from server1
5004 from server2 = 3 from server1
5005 from server2 = 4 from server1
```

Note: Just for example purpose I have given less records. Actual table contains some thousands of records.

Comment: Not related to your question but you could save memory by feeding the IDataReader from step1 into the WriteToServer in step2, skipping the datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no guarantee of order while bulk insert. So I added a temporary id column to the destination table. Flow will be as follows:

```
Step1: var dt = select *, id as tempId from server1.dbo.TableA order by id;
Step2: SQL bulk copy into server2 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
Step3: var resultDt = select top 4 id, tempId from server2.dbo.TableA order by id desc. Since we know the number of records we inserted I am using "top 4".
```

Now id will be the new id generated by server2 and tempId will be the id from server1. Problem solved :)

Comment: You're right in that there is no guarantee of order. When I had to do this via text files, I had an intermediate step of adding an "order" column as I read the file row by row. I then added that into my temp table and the utiliising that in my SqlBulkCopy example. There are a couple of useful links in comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10775945/685760) if you want to take a look.

Comment: Did you find any documentation from Microsoft about the guarantee of order?
This is not strictly about the order of insert, but rather about the order of identity generation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is available in the below link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee3d90b0-d212-4bf0-8f2a-5dcb716896eb/sqlbulkcopy-insert-order?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

- Create staging table(say tmp_tableA) with same structure of tableA
  without identity.
- Bulk copy the data into tmp_tableA.
- Now insert into tableA from tmp_tableA.