# C# SqlBulkcopy insert behaving differently on updating SQL Server from 2005 to 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have a table `Employee` with these columns:

1. ID int (primary key, with auto increment by 1)
2. Employee_Name
3. Salary
4. Joining_Date (clustered index with ASC order)

Now, when we are saving data using `SqlBulkCopy` from our C# application into a SQL Server 2005 database, it inserts the rows in same order of the Datatable rows.

But when we are saving that data into SQL Server 2014, then the order of rows changed according to clustered index column.

C# code:

```
DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable();

//Inserting employee records in datatable

bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtEmployee);
```

Please provide the behavioral changes if any and how to get it solved. Multiple design approaches are also welcomed

Two options we have are -

1. Ignore Bulkcopy and insert rows one by one. This has issue in the connection and it breaks due to network issues resulting in rollback
2. Store data in a table via bulkcopy having a timestamp column. This way we can run a job to fill data in the final table based on the timestamp by some job. This is less acceptable as per the current system.

This is Windows server 2008 with SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2014

Comment: There aren't any changes. The assumption about orders is wrong even in SQL Server 2005. The *only* physical order in a table is that of the clustered index. That's what `clustered` means - that the rows are stored in that index's order

Comment: [There are no guarantees about ordering in a bulk copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140065/sqlbulkcopy-insert-order)

Comment: SQL 2005 went out of support april 2016, and Win2k8 is also out of support.  Many things in the world have changed, if you want to see all the sql changes please read up on MS' website.

Comment: There's no order when *querying* the inserted data, unless specified by an `ORDER BY` clause. The server is free to return data in any order it sees fit unless there's an ORDER BY clause. For simple queries and *small* amounts of data, the rows *may* be returned in the clustered index's order. Any operation that partitions, hashes, caches data can change that order though

Comment: SQL Server 2005 would only return the data in the order of insertion if there was no clustered index, and then, only for simple queries

Comment: In SQL Server 2005, it ignoring the clustered index while inserting in table and allows to insert greater joining date before lesser value of joining date.

Comment: Another approach is to explicitly take out a range of identity values yourself (using `DBCC CHECKIDENT` and `DBCC CHECKIDENT(, ... RESEED)`, use these values in your data table, and explicitly insert values for the `ID` column with `KeepIdentity`. Using a sequence (SQL Server 2012+) and `sp_sequence_get_range` makes this more reliable/convenient, but would involve abandoning the identity, which might break other stuff.

Comment: And no, in SQL Server 2005 a bulk insert definitely did not ignore the clustered index either (this is impossible -- rows are stored in clustered index order *by definition*). You just got lucky that the bulk insert operation did not reorder the incoming rows when inserting them. Later versions of SQL Server are better at exploiting I/O throughput and minimal logging by avoiding writes to pages that are already being written to, so you will almost never observe those respecting the incoming row order. The only permanent fix is unambiguously adding an order yourself before inserting.

Comment: A relational table **doesn't** have any "system-inherent" ordering - it's just an **inherently UNordered bag** of data. The **only** reliable way to get data out in an ordered fashion is to `SELECT` and specify an **explicit** `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore, the insert **cannot** be "violating" or "ignoring" any ordering - there's no ordering - period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to be certain that a SQL bulk copy operation will leave you with records that you can retrieve in a certain order is to include a row number for each row.  If you already have the data ordered in your datatable, add another column to your SQL table and the datatable for an "insert row number" or something like that.

1. Add a numeric field to your datatable.
2. Put the row number in that field.
3. Add a numeric field for the row number to your SQL table
4. Do the bulkcopy
5. Use the row number field to determine which order the original data was in

Comment: We already specified this solution in second option in question.

Comment: A timestamp wouldn't necessarily be unique in a bulk copy operation.  I recommended something different, which is a row number for each row inserted in a given bulk copy operation.  That is different than your second solution.